# Diamond operator suggested, but causes an error

Tags: java, android

Android Studio complains that I'm not using the diamond operator, but unfortunately I cannot build it otherwise:

```
protected Pair<Boolean, Constructor<? extends ClipboardToken>> getTokenCreator(Class[] parameterTypes)
        throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Constructor<? extends ClipboardToken> constructor = tokenClass.getConstructor(parameterTypes);
    return new Pair<Boolean, Constructor<? extends ClipboardToken>>(this.constructor == constructor, constructor);
}
```

If I change it into a diamond operator in line 4 I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: Pair<Boolean,Constructor<CAP#1>> cannot be converted to Pair<Boolean,Constructor<? extends ClipboardToken>>
        return new Pair<>(this.constructor == constructor, constructor);
               ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends ClipboardToken from capture of ? extends ClipboardToken
```

Is there something I can do about it except to ignore the warning?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is a duplicate, it only becomes a compiler error when I use the diamond operator.

Comment: here it is being explained: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html ...and it is by far not the only duplicate [which can be found](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+CAP%231+is+a+fresh+type-variable) by that error message . `new Pair<>()` without the least type does not appear proper.

Comment: But it is `Pair<F,S>(F,S)`, so `S` is the type of the second argument which is `Constructor<? extends ClipboardToken>`, so why would it not be able to infer it automatically?